# Change Angular mat chip default colors

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, tags, styles

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to to change mat chip default colors using global CSS file but some reason it won't let me change the default chip color and inside text color.

Homepage.component HTML

```
      <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip>Tag1</mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
```

Global CSS

```
.mat-chip{
    background-color:mat-color($accent);
    color: mat-contrast($positive,50);
}
```

[This is what it look like inside mat-card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfsVG.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `mat-color($accent)` and `mat-contrast($positive,50)`?

Comment: Hi Michale, my senior dev created another global CSS theme file call styles-theme.scss and I'm referring the color from that file. he don't want me to hard coded in every element so I'm trying to change the chip color using that theme file.

I was able to change the colors of mat-card but I'm not sure why it won't let me change the color of mat-chip.

Comment: Then we might need to look at those functions. Also you are using **SCSS**. Please stop referring to CSS. They are different.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out but Thierry  Falvo comment already solved my problem. still Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `!important` operator, as below :

```
.mat-chip{
  background-color: mat-color($accent) !important;
  color: mat-contrast($positive,50) !important;
}
```

Comment: It work!, Thanks Thierry. Truly appreciate you help.

Comment: You're welcome, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, and upvote and accept, it's better than a comment ! Thanks.